# Open file at Vim startup

Tags: vim

I like to have Vim open a cheatsheet at startup. Adding this to _vimrc works nicely with MacVim:

```
:e *path-to-cheatsheet*
```

but on Windows, vim displays a message box at startup:

> ```
> "~\Dropbox\vimfiles\myvim\vimcheat.txt"
> "~\Dropbox\vimfiles\myvim\vimcheat.txt" [unix] 52L, 1735C
> ```

When the message box is dismissed, Vim completes startup and opens the cheatsheet. How do I get this to work cleanly with Windows Vim?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `~/.vimrc` is processed at the very beginning of `:help initialization`. You can use the `VimEnter` event to open the file after all the startup stuff is done:

```
autocmd VimEnter * edit path/to/cheatsheet
```

If you don't want to see the messages, use `silent edit`. If you don't care about errors (if the cheatsheet isn't there), use `silent!`.

Comment: Both suggestions work nicely. Thanks! Do you happen to understand why the original command, without silent, works on MacVim but causes Windows Vim to complain?

Comment: In Windows Vim, the GUI only becomes available later, therefore the message pop-ups. That may be different in MacVim;  you should not rely on that.

Comment: As this answers your few question, please accept my answer by clicking on the outlined checkmark next to it. Thanks!